# How to use IcedCoffeeScript on ExpressJS application

Tags: node.js, express, iced-coffeescript

the question is how can I use IcedCoffeeScript (http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script) on my web-application based on ExpressJS? Now I use vanilla CoffeeScript language in my application.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- install IcedCoffeeScript globally via npm (in similar way you installed CoffeeScript):

> npm -g install iced-coffee-script

- run your app written in IcedCoffeeScript (so Coffee + **await**, **defer** keywords)

> iced app.coffee

Btw, IcedCoffeeScript is a superset of Coffee, so you will be able to execute your code written in Coffee using **iced**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [nodemon](http://remy.github.io/nodemon/) with IcedCoffeeScript for development, like this: `nodemon -x iced app.iced`.